# Need to delete range of cells based on text criteria

Tags: excel

All, sorry, new to VBA and know this is an easy solution for those that aren't newbies.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Czjp6.png)

So what I need to do is to clear the data for Wks 1 - 4 but only for Apples.

I found code that will clear the entire row but having problems figuring out how to clear the contents in Wks 1 - 4 (columns B:E) but leave the word Apples in column A

Here is the code I have so far:
Sub testclear()

```
last = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = last To 1 Step -1
    If (Cells(i, "A").Value) = "Apples" Then
    Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Clear
    End If
Next i
```

End Sub

Comment: `Range(.Cells(i, 2), .Cells(i, 5)).Clear`?

Comment: Thanks, got it to work.  Appreciate the help.